# Расположение триггеров

Tags: sql-server, sql

Где можно посмотреть существующие триггеры?

Comment: Уточните СУБД?

Comment: SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

если просто нужно посмотреть - пользуйтесь Enterprise Manager
если нужно запросом - прочитайте sysobjects с типом xtype = 'TR'

Answer (score 1):

Management Studio/браузер объектов/таблицы/триггерная таблица/триггеры.

Comment: спасибо, ответы больше не требуются.